# How can I delete an element from a multidimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a tree structure on python using a multidimensional array on python. I'm using this line of code to create my list:

```
matrix = [[-1 for x in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
```

If I print the list it will return this:

```
[[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]]
```

**This next paragraph is a small explanation of what I'm doing just in case anyone is interested or if it helps you give a more complete solution for my problem. The actual question is in the next paragraph.**

The first position within the array is the key or name of the element, the second position is who is the parent node of the element, the third position tells you if the node has any children and the last two positions tell you who the predecessor and successor of the element are, if there are any.

**The question starts here:**

Anyway I'm also required to create a garbage collector that collects any node and its children if I were to choose to delete the node. However I don't know how to delete the entire element. I found another thread that suggested using something called pop to delete things from the multidimensional array. But from what I gathered after reading the answers the pop method only deletes an element within the list meaning it would only delete a -1 instead of deleting everything. So is there any method of deleting one lists within the list in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pop deletes an element in a list even if that element is a list so to remove the first list in matrix you can use

```
matrix.pop(0)
```

Comment: Really? I didn't know that I thought it just deleted an element inside the list that's within a list. Thanks for you help. I also found I can do this: 

x = int(input("Enter the node you want to delete: "))
matrix.remove(matrix[x])
print(matrix)

Comment: yea that is exactly the same but maybe slower because remove will scan all matrix element until it reaches martrix